# Rails Sorcery Gem Intermittent undefined method Exceptions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, sorcery

I'm using the [Sorcery](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery) gem (version 0.8.6) to authenticate `Company` records in a Rails 4.0.4 app.

The authentication flow is working fine, but I'm running into issues when trying to use Sorcery's submodules - `:reset_password` and `:user_activation`. Rails throws `undefined method` exceptions when calling instance methods defined in Sorcery submodules on instances of the `Company` record (`@company`):

[image: undefined method exception]

The issue exists **intermittently** and I can't reproduce in any logical way. 1% of the time `@company` will handle the method like it's supposed to, and doesn't the other 99% of the time.

In the screen above I have attempted to call `deliver_reset_password_instructions!`, which is defined in [reset_password.rb](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/blob/ab7d9c1e61c42cce630971e77a3f9af43224fccc/lib/sorcery/model/submodules/reset_password.rb).

My Sorcery initialiser (`config/initializers/sorcery.rb`) contains: `Rails.application.config.sorcery.submodules = [:reset_password, :user_activation]` and `config.user_class = "Company"`.

My Company model (`app/models/company.rb`) contains `authenticates_with_sorcery!`, which if I'm correct should include these submodules and extend the model with the methods defined in any configure submodules.

Worth mentioning that the same behaviour is happening with `send_activation_success_email!` and all the other instance methods defined in [user_activation.rb](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/blob/ab7d9c1e61c42cce630971e77a3f9af43224fccc/lib/sorcery/model/submodules/user_activation.rb) (I'm not directly calling it, but Sorcery only calls it 1% of the time on a successful Company create).

Been struggling with this for about 2 days now, have run out of ideas.

Any help is very much appreciated!

**Updates**

1. I've noticed it seems to work (`@company` responds to submodule defined instance methods) the first time after I leave the computer and come back after a few hours. It will continue to work until the Rails server is restarted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem!

I found it! 1.5 days later.

In my `rails_admin` initializer I had the lines:

```
Rails.application.eager_load!
config.included_models = ActiveRecord::Base.descendants.map!(&:name)
```

To address the issue described: sferik/rails_admin#1697

This didn't play well with Sorcery apparently.

All is well now.

More info:
[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery/issues/608)